# Pitch detection - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, fft

I'm currently developing an electron app, which I hope will be able to measure the *pitch* of guitar input on desktop.

My initial idea is one tone at a time so please let me know if FTT is appropriate.

*Edit: per comments it seems that FTT is not great so I'm considering using Harmonic Product Spectrum for example*

I don't have too much experience with node.js, but so far I've managed to fork the broken `microphone` package and tweak it a bit to be able to fetch a `wav` format data from `sox`.

This is the actual code that spawns the process and fetches the data (simplified, it actually has a `startCapture` method which spawns the recording process):

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

const audio = new PassThrough;
const info = new PassThrough;

const recordingProcess = spawn('sox', ['-d', '-t', 'wav', '-p'])
recordingProcess.stdout.pipe(audio);
recordingProcess.stderr.pipe(info);
```

And in another js file, I listen for the data event:

```
mic.startCapture({format: 'wav'});
mic.audioStream.on('data', function(data) {
    /* data is Uint8Array[8192] */
});
```

Ok so I'm getting an array of data which seems to be a good start.
I know I should be applying somehow a pitch detection algorithm to start the pitch analysis

Am I going in the right direction? What format should this data be in?
How can I use this data for pitch detection?

Comment: Yes! I love the idea btw, I hope you make a tuner of it ;) Always wanted a command-line guitar tuner.

Comment: Using the FFT is not a great way to measure [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(music)), especially if you want sufficient accuracy for a tuner. There are much better [pitch detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm), e.g. [Harmonic Product Spectrum](http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/%7Etrsmyth/analysis/Harmonic_Product_Spectrum.html). Note: there is subtle but important difference between *pitch* and *frequency* - you want to measure musical pitch, not frequency.

Comment: Read the above link about pitch - pitch is a *percept* - when you have a complex sound like a musical instrument playing a single note, there are multiple components (usually fundamental + harmonics, but some of these may be missing) - pitch is related to the fundamental frequency, but the perceived pitch may be different from the physical frequency of the fundamental. Note that frequency really only applies to a single component, whereas pitch applies to the whole complex sound. Only for a pure sine wave would they be the same.

Comment: Note also that there are dozens of very similar questions on SO already, usually people trying to implement instrument tuner apps or similar, and misguidedly thinking that all they need is an FFT - you might want to search for the tags [fft], [dsp], [pitch], [frequency], etc, or just "FFT tuner".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're getting a buffer with WAV data, you can use the [`wav-decoder`](https://github.com/mohayonao/wav-decoder) library to parse it, and then feed it to the [`pitchfinder`](https://github.com/peterkhayes/pitchfinder) library to obtain the frequency of the audio.

```javascript
const Pitchfinder = require('pitchfinder')
const WavDecoder = require('wav-decoder')
const detectPitch = new Pitchfinder.YIN()

const frequency = detectPitch(WavDecoder.decode(data).channelData[0])
```

However, since you're using Electron, you can also just use the MediaStream Recording API in Chromium.

First of all, this will only work with Electron 1.7+, because it uses Chromium 58, the first version of Chromium to include a fix for [a bug which prevented the `AudioContext` from decoding audio data from the `MediaRecorder`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673782).

Also, for the purposes of this code, I'll be using ES7 `async` and `await` syntax, which should run just fine on Node.js 7.6+ and Electron 1.7+.

So let's assume your `index.html` for Electron looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frequency Finder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tuner</h1>

    <div><label for="devices">Device:</label> <select id="devices"></select></div>

    <div>Pitch: <span id="pitch"></span></div>
    <div>Frequency: <span id="frequency"></span></div>

    <div><button id="record" disabled>Record</button></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

Now let's get to work on the `renderer` script. First, let's set a few variables we'll be using:

```javascript
const audioContext = new AudioContext()
const devicesSelect = document.querySelector('#devices')
const pitchText = document.querySelector('#pitch')
const frequencyText = document.querySelector('#frequency')
const recordButton = document.querySelector('#record')
let audioProcessor, mediaRecorder, sourceStream, recording
```

Alright, now onto the rest of the code. First, let's populate that `<select>` drop down in the Electron window with all the available audio input devices.

```javascript
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
  devices.forEach(device => {
    if (device.kind === 'audioinput') {
      const option = document.createElement('option')
      option.textContent = device.label
      option.value = device.deviceId
      fragment.appendChild(option)
    }
  })
  devicesSelect.appendChild(fragment)

  // Run the event listener on the `<select>` element after the input devices
  // have been populated. This way the record button won't remain disabled at
  // start.
  devicesSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
})
```

You'll notice at the end, we call an event that we've set on the `<select>` element in the Electron window. But, hold on, we never wrote that event handler! Let's add some code **above** the code we just wrote:

```javascript
// Runs whenever a different audio input device is selected by the user.
devicesSelect.addEventListener('change', async e => {
  if (e.target.value) {
    if (recording) {
      stop()
    }

    // Retrieve the MediaStream for the selected audio input device.
    sourceStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        deviceId: {
          exact: e.target.value
        }
      }
    })

    // Enable the record button if we have obtained a MediaStream.
    recordButton.disabled = !sourceStream
  }
})
```

Let's also actually write a handler for the record button, because at this moment it does nothing:

```javascript
// Runs when the user clicks the record button.
recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recording) {
    stop()
  } else {
    record()
  }
})
```

Now we display audio devices, let the user select them, and have a record button... but we still have unimplemented functions - `record()` and `stop()`.

Let's stop right here to make an architectural decision.

We can record the audio, grab the audio data, and analyse it to obtain its pitch, all in `renderer.js`. However, analysing the data for pitch is an expensive operation. Therefore, it would be good to have the ability to run that operation out-of-process.

Luckily, Electron 1.7 brings in support for web workers with a Node context. Creating a web worker will allow us to run the expensive operation in a different process, so it doesn't block the main process (and UI) while it is running.

So keeping this in mind, let's assume that we will create a web worker in `audio-processor.js`. We'll get to the implementation later, but we'll assume it accepts a message with an object, `{sampleRate, audioData}`, where `sampleRate` is the sample rate, and `audioData` is a `Float32Array` which we'll pass to `pitchfinder`.

Let's also assume that:

- If processing of the recording succeeded, the worker returns a message with an object `{frequency, key, octave}` - an example would be `{frequency: 440.0, key: 'A', octave: 4}`.
- If processing of the recording failed, the worker returns a message with `null`.

Let's write our `record` function:

```javascript
function record () {
  recording = true
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop recording'

  if (!audioProcessor) {
    audioProcessor = new Worker('audio-processor.js')

    audioProcessor.onmessage = e => {
      if (recording) {
        if (e.data) {
          pitchText.textContent = e.data.key + e.data.octave.toString()
          frequencyText.textContent = e.data.frequency.toFixed(2) + 'Hz'
        } else {
          pitchText.textContent = 'Unknown'
          frequencyText.textContent = ''
        }
      }
    }
  }

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(sourceStream)

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async e => {
    if (e.data.size !== 0) {
      // Load the blob.
      const response = await fetch(URL.createObjectURL(data))
      const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
      // Decode the audio.
      const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer)
      const audioData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)
      // Send the audio data to the audio processing worker.
      audioProcessor.postMessage({
        sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate,
        audioData
      })
    }
  }

  mediaRecorder.start()
}
```

Once we start recording with the `MediaRecorder`, we won't get our `ondataavailable` handler called until recording is stopped. This is a good time to write our `stop` function.

```javascript
function stop () {
  recording = false
  mediaRecorder.stop()
  recordButton.textContent = 'Record'
}
```

Now all that's left is to create our worker in `audio-processor.js`. Let's go ahead and create it.

```javascript
const Pitchfinder = require('pitchfinder')

// Conversion to pitch from frequency based on technique used at
// https://www.johndcook.com/music_hertz_bark.html

// Lookup array for note names.
const keys = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']

function analyseAudioData ({sampleRate, audioData}) {
  const detectPitch = Pitchfinder.YIN({sampleRate})

  const frequency = detectPitch(audioData)
  if (frequency === null) {
    return null
  }

  // Convert the frequency to a musical pitch.

  // c = 440.0(2^-4.75)
  const c0 = 440.0 * Math.pow(2.0, -4.75)
  // h = round(12log2(f / c))
  const halfStepsBelowMiddleC = Math.round(12.0 * Math.log2(frequency / c0))
  // o = floor(h / 12)
  const octave = Math.floor(halfStepsBelowMiddleC / 12.0)
  const key = keys[Math.floor(halfStepsBelowMiddleC % 12)]

  return {frequency, key, octave}
}

// Analyse data sent to the worker.
onmessage = e => {
  postMessage(analyseAudioData(e.data))
}
```

Now, if you run this all together... **it won't work!** Why?

We need to update `main.js` (or whatever the name of your main script is) so that when the main Electron window gets created, Electron is told to provide Node support in the context of the web worker. Otherwise, that `require('pitchfinder')` doesn't do what we want it to do.

This is simple, we just need to add `nodeIntegrationInWorker: true` in the window's `webPreferences` object. For example:

```javascript
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
  }
})
```

Now, if you run what you've put together, you'll get a simple Electron app that lets you record a small section of audio, test its pitch, and then display that pitch to screen.

This will work best with small snippets of audio, as the longer the audio, the longer it takes to process.

If you want a more complete example that goes more in depth, such as the ability to listen and return pitch live instead of making the user click record and stop all the time, take a look at the [electron-tuner app](https://github.com/vsimonian/electron-tuner) that I've made. Feel free to look through the source to see how things are done - I've done my best to make sure it is well commented.

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Screenshot of electron-tuner]

Hopefully all this helps you in your efforts.

Comment: Just letting you know that I made a node-addon for the pitchfinder repo (named node-pitchfinder). It is much faster (in my project I'm running real-time detection on multiple channels, so I needed it to be faster). I've also implemented MacLeod's algorithm, which performs better for instruments (at least I think so for the guitar)

Comment: Clicking record does nothing, and clicking stop results in the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined`